# How to perform an task in the background?

Tags: java, android

I want to use WorkRequest to run a task in the background on a daily basis. But I have two problems:

1. These codes are executed again each time when the app runs.
2. When the app is closed, the code will not be executed.

I also want the code to run when the program is closed

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a Handler or you can use workManager.

WorkManager works on devices runnig Android 5.0 or higher.So, if your min sdk version is higher or equal to that , prefer using that.Work Manager is used for deferrable tasks generally like sending analytics event etc.

Comment: Yes, I use WorkManager. But when the program runs again, the task also runs. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()` method to schedule your work. There will be only one instance of that work.
`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` keeps the existing work and ignore the new request each time the app is started.

Example:

```
   WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
           "UNIQUE_TAG",
           ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
           yourWorkRequest
)
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#unique-work

Comment: I used this but it does not run periodically. I also want the code to run when the program is closed

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to perform a task in the background threads and not use it from the UI thread.

1. using the AysnkTask. Tutorial : [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
2. using RxJava. RxJava helps you to perform tasks in other threads and even manage the consequence of a task to perform in which thread. Tutorial [RxJava](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)